# Kubernetes is Down

Tags: kubernetes

All of a sudden, I get this error when I run kubectl commands

```
The connection to the server xx.xx.xxx.xx:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I can see kubelet running, but none of the other Kubernetes related services are running.

```
docker ps -a | grep kube-api
```

returns me nothing.

What I did after searching for the resolution in google:

1. Turned off swap --> *issue persists*
2. Restarted the linux machine -->
   *Right after restart, I could see the kubectl commands giving me output, but after about 15 seconds, it again went back to the error I mentioned above.*
3. Restarted Kubelet --> For 1 sec, I could see the output for kubectl commands, but again back to square one.

I'm not sure what exactly I'm supposed to do here.

NB: K8 cluster is installed with kubeadm
Also, I can see the pods in **EVICTED** state for a brief time when I could see the kubectl get pods output

Comment: It depends of how you installed your kubernetes, but probably you have used  kubeadm, kops or kubespray. Try to restart kubelet , that should bring back to life all the k8s containers, if not have a look to kubelet logs.

Comment: K8 is installed with Kubeadm. I tried restarting kubelet as well. But same error

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by returning nothing - is there no reaction to the command at all? What kind of CNI are you using? Also the swap should be turned off before the installation of kubeadm or at least before the initialization of the cluster. Did you follow some tutorial or it's already a bigger environment - meaning if you can easily try again with kubeadm reset? Maybe the journalctl --unit kubelet / docker logs <container_id> would give us some more information, did you configure labels in the cluster? Please post the results and we will try to troubleshoot the issue.